# British equivalent of "Can I get a ... "

Tags: word-usage, british-english

BBC [listed](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-14201796) *'Can I get a...'* as the most irksome Americanism. Then what is the most British way of making an order?

Comment: "Could I please have...?" followed by awkward shuffling as you try to avoid making eye contact with the server or anyone else in the shop.

Comment: @JohnClifford lol why would one avoid eye contact? Just curious!

Comment: Self-effacing is the British way, eye contact may be considered aggressive, same as on the subway in NYC, if sys contact is necessary then always with a smile.

Comment: It's a bit of an in-joke with us Brits, MAKZ. As Peter says, self-effacing is like one of our stereotypes. As is apologising for everything and drinking lots of tea.

Comment: Thanks for writing guys. I have also found the answer in [EnglishSE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/why-is-can-i-get-replacing-could-i-have). Brits have always amazed me.

Comment: I'm surprised no-one has pointed out that we *British* naturally tend to express things more obliquely than Americans. So we usually ask ***Do you have a...?***, since it's contextually obvious that if they *do* have it, we want it. (For the less-well-educated, it's ***'Ave you gotta [light, boy]?***)

Comment: You might want to wait to accept an answer until you get one that contains fewer errors.

Comment: @snailboat ok... waiting till tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,  let me point out that is should be written as

> **Can I getta**...?

which is asking about the possibility of having something, possibly in a particular way.
The BrE equivalents might be

> Please could I have...
>   Could I please have...
>   I would like to have...
>   Would it be possible to have... if it's not too much trouble.

Some examples

> AmE **Can I getta pint of beer**, *(please)*?
>   BrE ***(A)*** **lager, please**  *(pint is understood as the default in any pub)*
>
> AmE **Can I get that on a roll**?
>   BrE **Please could I have that on a bap**.
>
> AmE **Can I getta hamburger without pickles and lettuce**?
>   BrE **Would it be possible to have the hamburger without pickles and salad**?
>   *if the hamburger has already been order then **Sorry** is prefixed to the request*
>   BrE **Sorry, would it be possible to have the hamburger...**
>
> AmE **Can I getta train there**?
>   BrE **Would you know if the overland or tube goes there**?

Comment: I was with you up until the point where you said an American would start a sentence with "sorry". :P

Comment: @JohnClifford awwww ... :D

Comment: I have added annotations to my answer, apologies for not having them in earlier.

Comment: Hehe, +1 for bap.

Comment: Gonna, hadda, gotta, getta. Are you saying "Let's **getta** move on" is "Let's **get to** move on" and not "Let's **get a** move on"?

Comment: It's misleading at best to say it "should" be written *getta*.  That's a non-standard spelling, and learners generally should *not* spell it that way.